# Format cells in Excel with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I download table data using export to excel.

In the Excel file, the 13-digit number is displayed as `5.01001E+13`  (exponential value).

I need to display the value as a 13-digit number in excelsheet using AngularJS.

Example of the issue:

Comment: The number is just a string (you don't want to do maths with an account number). Cast the value to a string and you should be good to go.

Comment: What I am asking is, after download, the value need to display as number. Not as exponential value. I need code for that.

Comment: If you read my comment I think I am giving you the way to exactly that. Show your existing code if you want us to explain how to change it to achieve the desired output.